# Ember tabs with components

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to write an `Ember.Component` to handle Bootstrap-style tabs. I implemented it as a reusable `TabHolderComponent` which takes an array as parameter and outputs one tab per item and then one content container per item (à la Bootstrap). So far it works well, but I also need to be able to refresh the content in the tabs with a button in the tab. Is there an elegant way of sending a refresh event/action to a child component?

I have several different solutions to this (moving the refresh button into the component, which would be less user-friendly, or binding a parent component `refresh` property that contains the name of the tabs that should be refreshed and that the child component observes), but none of them are elegant.

I also saw [this suggestion](http://www.samselikoff.com/blog/2014/05/16/getting-ember-components-to-respond-to-actions/), but don't know how to make that work for dynamically created tabs where I can't hardcode the tab name as a parent component property.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the observable pattern (It's similar to what this post is saying).

```
{{my-thing parent=controller}}

App.MyThingComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  setup: function(){
    this.get('parent').register(this); // you should check to see if parent exists, I'm lazy
  }.on('init'),
  sayHello: function(){
    console.log('hello');
  }
});
```

And in the parent controller (Array, Object, or plain controller)

```
App.FooController = Em.Controller.extend({
  observers: null,
  setup: function(){
    this.observers = [];
  }.on('init'),
  register: function(observer){
    this.observers.pushObject(observer);
  },
  talkToChildren: function(){
    this.observers.forEach(function(child){
      child.sayHello();
    });
  }
});
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yoyod/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that looks like a good suggestion. I would however like to keep all the component-specific logic in the components, and not involve the controller if possible, to make them easily reusable.

Comment: There is no other way to communicate with a component outside of the component other than using an observer pattern.